# My Viber aborts unexpectedly while launching on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, viber

Im using ubuntu 14.04.

I have downloaded the latest version of viber for linux from the [official source](http://www.viber.com/en/products/linux).

I installed it though terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i viber.deb
```

and it got installed successfully without any error, but whenever I try to open it from dash or anywhere it closes within 2 second. I have used viber for more than 7 months and this thing happened this week only.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Launch it from the terminal and see if there are any error messages?

Comment: tell me the command to run it on terminal please.

Comment: Open terminal and write `/opt/viber/Viber `

Comment: okay i will check and let you know :)

Comment: @shaddy this shows when i run `/opt/viber/Viber` through terminal
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Answer (score 2):

Viber always aborts on startup when you have installed acestream package.
Just uninstall acestream:

```
apt-get remove acestream*
```

And then try to launch Viber again.
Tested on Ubuntu Desktop 14/15.

Answer (score 0):

do not open it with `dpkg`, first remove it then right click on the .deb file and open it with `ubuntu software center` and install it from there.

Comment: yes bro i did install it with software center even. :| same result

Comment: are you using 32bit or 64 operating system??

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit